# how to add gif image in imageview in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I followed the android developer site to add gif image in my application. But the image is not showing as animated, it shows like a normal image.

**Animation in drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/los01" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/los02" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

**Coding**

```
layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
                img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mylosanim);
                AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)  img.getBackground();
                frameAnimation.start();
                tv1.setText("Sorry!!!Play Again!!!");
                tv3.setText("Your Level-1 Score:"+Integer.toString(score));
                layout.setClickable(true);
                frameAnimation.stop();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches including the use of [`Movie`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie.html) class.

Take a look at [Tutorial: How to play animated GIFs in Android](http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/) and the related posts for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

try as

```
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)img.getBackground();  
        if (frameAnimation.isRunning()){  
            frameAnimation.stop();  
        }else{  
            frameAnimation.stop();  
            frameAnimation.start();

                tv1.setText("Sorry!!!Play Again!!!");
                tv3.setText("Your Level-1 Score:"+Integer.toString(score));
                layout.setClickable(true);
        }
```